# Creating separate objects with a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a variable `player.result` which is created six times. Each of these times it is added to `player.participant.taxGame.totincome`.

Although it is not clear from the code (this is part of an app), this line works properly. So `player.result` is neatly added to `player.participant.taxGame.totincome` six times.

I however want to store each of those instances of `player.result` seperately in a variables which is called something like `player.round1`, `player.round2` etc. I have tried to do this with a for loop.

It currently looks like this:

```
player.participant.taxGame.totincome = player.participant.taxGame.totincome + player.result;
for ( i=1; i < 6; i++) {
    player.rounds[i] = player.result
};
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the types of your variables and where your error is

Comment: Yes I understand. I am working in an app that someone else created which makes it slightly complicated. I should perhaps add that the first line works properly.

Comment: From what I see, you're setting 6 elements in an array (`player.rounds`) with the same value: `player.result`

Comment: Your description makes no sense. "*I have a variable `player.result` which is created six times.*" No, `player.result` is not a variable, and variables are created once, not six times. Show code; don't paraphrase it.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for your constructive criticism. I am just trying to explain it the best I can at the moment with my limited javascript experience.

Comment: Did you initialized the `player.rounds` variable before in your code?

Comment: @Tom That's usually a bad idea, even for people with more experience. Actual code is almost always better than a description of the code in English.

Comment: @melpomene The problem is that this code comes from within an app which is not created by me. Adding more code (that refers to even more code), would unlikely make the problem any clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push your result to an array which represent the rounds.

```
player.participant.taxGame.totincome = player.participant.taxGame.totincome + player.result;

player.rounds.push(player.result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do I have to initialise `player.rounds = []` somehwere?

Comment: Sorry, newbie here. But I got it to work. Thank you!